# Neural network loss value not changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am new in deep learning, so I made this model, to train my Data, I tried many combinations, adding layers, changing the activation function, changing the loss function, but the loss is not decreasing. 
Seeking for your help guys.

my training_data contain 1000 samples: 1000 raws, and 20 columns all numbers, outputs: a list of 4 numbers 
here is my model:

```
from keras import models
from keras.models import Sequential


from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten , Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras import optimizers

scaler = StandardScaler()
input_shape = x_train[0].shape
x_train_std = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='sigmoid' , input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='sigmoid' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
#sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.85, nesterov=True)
#opt = SGD(lr=0.1, nesterov=True)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.87, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=sgd)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)
history = model.fit(x_train_std, y_train , validation_split=0.1, epochs=100, batch_size=1 , callbacks = [es])#,
```

Comment: Is this a classification or regression problem?

Comment: can you please explain the dataset, or how it looks like, loss value is heavily influenced by the dataset

Comment: @desertnaut it is a  multi regression problem, the outputs are four numbers all positives and when summed should be equal to one

Comment: @Damzaky, here the first rows of my Dataset      , it contains  20 labels and 1000 samples:  less than one :                         
      array([[0.00091693, 0.00091528, 0.00091285, ..., 0.00088302, 0.00088099,
        0.00087953],
       [0.00079937, 0.00079768, 0.00079567, ..., 0.00077222, 0.0007711 ,
        0.00077031],
       [0.00057827, 0.00057821, 0.00057825, ..., 0.00057288, 0.0005722 ,
        0.00057154],
       ...,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in a regression setting, you should *not* use `softmax` as activation function of your last layer - a `linear` activation (which is the default one, if not defined) should be used here.

Sigmoid activations are also highly not advisable for the intermediate layers - use `relu` instead.

Additionally, you should not use dropout by default - start without it, and only add it if it improves your validation performance.

All in all, here is what your model should look like for starters:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu' , input_shape=input_shape))
# model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='relu' ))
# model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='relu' ))
# model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(4)) # default activation='linear'
```

where you can uncomment the dropout layers only if needed (and not necessarily altogether).

Trying the Adam optimizer is also a good idea for a first approach:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

Finally, you should definitely increase your `batch_size` (try 64 or 128 for starters).

Comment: Thank for your answer,  I tried the changes you made in the script, well the loss is decreasing, but not as I expected, do you think adding more layers would help?

Comment: @Moh It could, as also more nodes per layer. There are no ready-made answers in such cases, experimentation is everything (once you have avoided fundamental mistakes, such as the ones pointed out in the answer).